# Midje on travis-ci fails with NoSuchMethodError: KeywordLookupSite.<init>

Tags: clojure, leiningen, travis-ci, midje

I'm trying to use the [Midje](http://github.com/marick/Midje) testing framework for Clojure on the [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org/) service.

The `project.clj` looks like this:

```
(defproject my-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Example"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[midje "1.3.0"]
                     [lein-midje "1.0.7"]])
```

I added a `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: clojure
script: "lein midje"
```

Running `lein midje` locally (Ubuntu 11.10) works fine, but on Travis CI the build fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.<init>(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V
at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:417)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.<init>(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V
at leiningen.util.paths$native_arch_path.<clinit>(paths.clj:32)
at leiningen.util.paths__init.load(Unknown Source)
at leiningen.util.paths__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at leiningen.core$loading__4414__auto__.invoke(core.clj:1)
at leiningen.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
at leiningen.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
... 11 more
```

Why does the error occur on Travis CI, but not my machine? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Here is the solution that worked for me: http://clojure-play-framework.blogspot.com/2012/01/re-new-version-of-clojurescript-one.html

Answer (score 3):

After unsuccessful searches for the cause of this problem, I came across a [GitHub project](https://github.com/duck1123/ciste) that seemed to be using Midje with Travis CI successfully. I also could get it to work using the following workaround:

```
(defproject my-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Example"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[midje "1.3.0" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]
                     [lein-midje "1.0.7"]])
```

I posted the question and the workaround here to make it more accessible.

I'm still interested in information about the root cause and in alternative solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was running into the same problem locally. Nuking the lib directory in my project, adding the :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure] bit, and then running 'lein deps' again did the trick for me.

Comment: KeywordLookupSite not found is mainly there when running clojure 1.3 code with clojure 1.2. I think you should upgrade midje.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this recently, but I was using lein2 instead of lein.  For lein2, project.clj should have at least:

```
{:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[midje "1.6.0" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]]
                  :plugins [[lein-midje "3.1.3"]]}}
```

And .travis.yml should include:

```
script: lein2 midje
```